# Alfresco Pgadmin4

Tags: alfresco

I am still struggling in vain to install Alfresco. After trying Docker and not being able to edit the configs to sort the user not displaying issue i tried Loftux's installer but that failed after a reboot and i havent had a response on thier forum (see Install troubles #148). Undaunted i turned to Abhinav Kumar Mishra's excellent instructions here. However when you reach config_distro.py there are no files at all in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/

Both Pythons are installed, if i run python -V && python3 -V, i get;

Python 2.7.5
Python 3.6.8

I installed pgadmin4 using

$ sudo rpm -Uvh https://yum.postgresql.org/11/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm
$ sudo yum install pgadmin4 -y

Becuase it wasnt in my Centos 7 repositary. It seems to installe OK, no errors and i have re-installed a few times, but no dice. Surely i cannot be the only one with this issue? Any thoughts?

Regards, David

Comment: What version of Alfresco? When you say "After trying Docker and not being able to edit the configs to sort the user not displaying issue", could you be more specific about where the user(s) are not displaying?

Comment: Hi Curtis, thanks for coming back to me. I am installing 6.2, my problem with docker is definitely my issue. The reason i moved to a 'standard' install is i had no idea how to get to config files when running within docker.

Comment: In the docker compose yaml, you'd pass the config options in the java options.  I'll put an example as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to modify the effective share-config.xml in the share container:

1. Create a new share image based on the alfresco share image via dockerfile

   ```
    FROM alfresco/alfresco-share:6.2.2.4

    RUN sed -i 's@<show-authorization-status>true</show-authorization-status>@<show-authorization-status>false</show-authorization-status>@' $TOMCAT_DIR/webapps/share/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/share-config.xml
   ```

2. Create a volume for the share app so that direct edits to the share-config.xml persist across restarts (uses version "3" yaml):

   ```
    share:
        image: alfresco/alfresco-share:6.2.2.4
        volumes:
            - share:/usr/local/tomcat
        environment:
            REPO_HOST: "alfresco"
            REPO_PORT: "8080"
            JAVA_OPTS: "
                -Xms500m
                -Xmx500m
                -Dalfresco.host=localhost
                -Dalfresco.port=8080
                -Dalfresco.context=alfresco
                -Dalfresco.protocol=http
                "

    .
    . <bottom of docker compose yml>
    .


    volumes:
        share:
   ```
3. Create a custom share AMP containing a share-config-custom.xml file with the following:

   ```
   <alfresco-config>
   <config replace="true" evaluator="string-compare" condition="Users">
     <users>
         <!-- minimum length for username and password -->
         <username-min-length>2</username-min-length>
         <password-min-length>3</password-min-length>
         <show-authorization-status>false</show-authorization-status>
      </users>
      <enable-external-users-panel>false</enable-external-users-panel>
   </config>    

    </alfresco-config>
   ```

Comment: Thank you Curtis, appreciated. What i was trying to do is edit \tomcat\webapps\share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\share-config.xml to set the property to false on line 132. But i have no idea where share-config is in docker?

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect editing the share-config.xml file